# Non manifold errors in model for 3d printing

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

Hi I am starting out with Blender for 3d printing.
I am currently trying to make a shelf with three partial holes to hold toothbrush chargers.

My blender file is https://seafile.goblinshark.co.uk/f/c494ad743d/

I designed this by making the whole shape first, replicating it three times and then did a boolean subtraction from a cube.

This has left me with a few internal geometries inside the cube. But there are quite a few non manifold errors and I can't seam to add the top face of my cube while leaving the holes.

The idea is something like this image.

[image: screenshot of desired result]

Is there a list that describes the non manifold errors?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: the shape/curve is not regular at the begin of the arches curves (two very close vertices), is that wanted ?

Comment: I'd say that if there's no backup of shapes *before* applying Boolean, then it's easier to remodel. Boolean couldn't handle with something and left most parts of model without faces; thus it won't be manifold and of course this won't be printable.

Comment: You can enable the 3d print Toolbox addon (ships with default Blender), and click the 'Make manifold' box.  Only problem is, the entire model disappears when I use that command on your model!  LOL sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: There is an operator you can execute in edit mode called "select non manifold" after calling it, in the tool shelf there's a panel with non manifold cases. You can tick one box at a time and see which faces get selected each time.

Comment: Lemon. No I hadn't seen that. I will try to remove those and see if it helps. Thanks.

Duarte I have selected non manifold but its not that useful when it selects all vertices. Similar to the make manifold problem Mike mentioned.

Comment: Try the usual, recalculate normals, remove doubles etc. Otherwise post your blender so we can look at it.